# How to reliably get session id generated by Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Using the latest analytics.js code (as of today) is there a way through their JS API I can get the session id?

Comment: No, Session IDs are calculated on the backend of GA. The Answers given here relate to Client IDs.

Comment: @BNazaruk: not true for GA4 any more. Session IDs are on the browser, together with the Client ID.

Comment: Indeed, for GA4, you can now get it on the front-end. That answer related to UA tho. GA4 is meant to reduce the cost of Analytics for Google, so no more session generation on the backend. And the session definitions became much much simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're talking about the client ID, you can get that as follows:

```
ga(function(tracker) {
  var clientId = tracker.get('clientId');
  console.log(clientId);
});
```

Here's where that's stated in the documentation:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id#getting_the_client_id_from_the_cookie

Keep in mind that the client ID is (usually) stored in a cookie, so if the user clears their cookies, they'll be assigned a new client ID that may not match the one you have.

Comment: `tracker` is undefined, what should I do?

Comment: That most likely means you haven't created a tracker yet. You need to do that first, e.g. `ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto')`.

Comment: Hi @PhilipWalton what if he means really SESSION_ID [described here](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/13-useful-custom-dimensions-for-google-analytics/#1-2-session-id) for GTM?

Answer (score 7):

Using Google Tags and Google Analytics 4, the following code will get the `session_id` (tested code), please note G-XXXXXXXXXX is a placeholder for your analytics ID:

```
gtag('get', 'G-XXXXXXXXXX', 'session_id', (id) => { console.log(id); } );
```

will output to the console:

> 1678297554

Answer (score 2):

You can read the cookie created by Google **but**:

1. It's a privately (by google) chosen variable name/format and could change at any time, thus breaking your code
2. It appears to break their TOS if you store that information

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/51866/can-you-track-one-users-session-with-google-analytics-by-using-the-utma-cooki

[Linking Google Analytics event logs to unique session ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060707/linking-google-analytics-event-logs-to-unique-session-id)

http://www.analytics-ninja.com/blog/2011/08/how-google-analytics-calculates-visits.html

Comment: Those links refer to the old ga.js. I'm looking for info about the newer analytics.js.

Comment: @adam0101 my answer still stands: "It's a privately (by google) chosen variable name/format and could change at any time, thus breaking your code" You could download the JS file and look through it yourself to find your answer, but it would be unsupported and not recommended

Answer (score 1):

Be aware! Some ad-blockers like *uBlock Origin* replaces GA script with its own polyfill.
This means that you can't correctly check is it real GA script are loaded on your page.

Also *uBlock*'s polyfill changes GA API, so when you using `ga(function(tracker){})` **callback will never called**!
So don't relay on callback and never wait for its calling

The better way is to manually store custom `clientId` in cookie and tell this `clientId` to GA
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference?hl=en#clientId